# when java current memory does not reach max memory(defined by "Xmx"), is the remaining memory wasted?

Tags: java, linux, memory, virtual-memory

when java current memory does not reach max memory(defined by "Xmx"), the remaining memory (=max-current) is free and not used by any other process?
By the way, I know about virtual memory, if java process applys for 1G memory, does "1G" contain virtual memory?

Comment: Not if it's never been used, it isn't allocated yet.

Comment: 1. when java current memory does not reach max memory...? No. 2 1G memory, does "1G" contain virtual memory? The answer is that it is up to the OS. But the concept of "virtual memory" has been blurred by a number of factors, as the concept of memory only consisting of RAM and disc meaning a hard drive has been greatly blurred.

Comment: using `-Xms` and `-Xmx`, you can specify the _smallest_ amount of memory to use (ms), and/or the _largest_ amount of memory to use (mx). you're allowed to use neither, both, or either one by itself. if you want to allocate a specific amount up front, and never exceed that, set -Xms and -Xmx to the same thing (ex: 1GB). or you could start with something small (-Xms) and then provide an upper limit (-Xmx). this latter sounds like what you're doing, which is just setting an upper limit, not actually allocating anything.

Answer (score 1):

The Xmx option generally does not allocate memory (virtual or otherwise), so there is nothing to waste.

Xmx specifies the maximum that can be allocated.

Xms is the initial size of the heap, though it may not actually have real memory backing the entire heap, until used.

The memory allocation model in modern operating systems is rather more complicated than the simple question supposes. If the JVM requests a certain amount of "memory" from the OS, that "memory" is virtual memory -- which is to say, it might exist in RAM, it might exist on the disk in a page/swap file, or it might not exist anywhere; this latter is generally referred to as "demand-zero" pages: as soon as you touch them, they will exist, initially zeroed.

There may be an option to "pretouch" all pages of the initial heap allocation, which will cause them to exist in RAM, though they might subsequently be paged out.

Comment: I recommend that you run `pmap` against a program that uses `-xmx` with a large number, and then reconsider your first paragraph.